# How to duplicate rows in microsoft excel and make the first row negative and the second positive

Tags: excel

I have an `excel` files with numbers. I want to duplicated the numbers and make the first one negative and the second one positive. Please refer to the sample below.

For example

**Before**

```
3
5
6
7
```

**After**

```
-3
3
-5
5
-6
6
-7
7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may some better way but I have this right now. Try below formula

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,"-","") & INDIRECT("A"&INT((ROW()+1)/2))
```

[image]